# libglu1-mesa-dev, how to keep both i386 and amd64 packages

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, mesa

I'm using ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit

I want to build both 32-bit and 64-bit app under 64-bit Ubuntu.

I have a problem with package **libglu1-mesa-dev**, when I install i386 package, it removes amd64, and vice versa.

Is it possible to keep both packages, i386 and amd64?

```
    ~$ sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev:amd64
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
        gcc-4.8-base:i386 libdrm-dev:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
        libdrm-radeon1:i386 libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386
        libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-vivid:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386
        libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libllvm3.6:i386
        libpciaccess0:i386 libpthread-stubs0-dev:i386 libstdc++6:i386
        libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libx11-6:i386 libx11-dev:i386 libx11-xcb-dev:i386
        libx11-xcb1:i386 libxau-dev:i386 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386
        libxcb-dri2-0-dev:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-dev:i386
        libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-glx0-dev:i386 libxcb-present-dev:i386
        libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0:i386 libxcb-randr0-dev:i386
        libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-render0-dev:i386 libxcb-shape0:i386
        libxcb-shape0-dev:i386 libxcb-sync-dev:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386
        libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxcb-xfixes0-dev:i386 libxcb1:i386 libxcb1-dev:i386
        libxdamage-dev:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp-dev:i386 libxdmcp6:i386
        libxext-dev:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes-dev:i386 libxfixes3:i386
        libxshmfence-dev:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm-dev:i386
        libxxf86vm1:i386
    Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
    The following extra packages will be installed:
        libgl1-mesa-dev mesa-common-dev
    The following packages will be REMOVED:
        libgl1-mesa-dev:i386 libglu1-mesa-dev:i386 mesa-common-dev:i386
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
        libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev mesa-common-dev
    0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 3 to remove and 145 not upgraded.
    Need to get 0 B/536 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 178 kB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to the fact that both packages (amd64 and i386) have conflicting files, both packages cannot be installed together.

You can open a bug request on Debian or Ubuntu to get some attention on this matter.